# How can I get an interactive shell inside a Google datalab container?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I need to install additional software in a Google datalab container that runs with docker. It is possible to run bash commands with `%%bash ...`. However, this does not allow interactivity. So, I need an interactive shell within the container.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to modify the Datalab image you can write a new Dockerfile based on it like @Rambler suggested, or you can fork your own version, Datalab is [open source](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try running the container in interactive mode in the following way :

```
docker run -it --name=<container_name> <image>:<tag> /bin/bash
```

If the container is already running , you can leverage `docker exec` :

```
docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash
```

Comment: It works, but it seems that when I do that the changes are not permanent. Here is some info: http://www.ifconfig.it/wordpress/2015/05/docker-installsw/

Comment: Yeah , you would have to commit the container after your changes to retain them.Instead you can also write a Dockerfile with the install commands for required software and then generate an updated image.Here the datalab's image will be the base image.

Comment: It also seems that changes are not made in the running container, because the file system stays the same when I look at it from the jupyter notebook that runs in the cloud.

Comment: Weird.You can just run a simple test , for ex. , just create a file in a running container, commit it , and then re run it.That file should be present there.

Comment: It is really weird. To access the notebook I have to start the docker container. I can access the container and I see the changes in the file system. But when I use the jupyter notebook the filesystem looks unchanged!?!

Comment: Can you share more details? What commands are you running? Are you saying if you ssh into the running container and create a directory under the Jupyter notebook root, the file browser still can't see it?